How to Retrieve the Number of Opt-Outs with api from a Survey Sent via email with SurveyMonkey API?
I used the SurveyMonkey API to send a survey via email using a collector. Now that I have received some responses, I noticed that a few people clicked on the opt-out link.
How can I retrieve the number of people who opted out of the survey? Is there a specific API endpoint or method to get this information?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!
when I am adding the contact list i am getting the opt-out contact list but as responses i want what is recipients  status like opt-out ,responded
